# Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. React native update iOS 14

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

ERROR    Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

Hi all, I'm updating some dependencies:

- react-native (0.61.5) to (0.63.2)
- react-navigation (^4.0.10) to (^4.4.0)
- react-native-screens ^2.11.0 (new add)

Current Package.json:

```
{
  ...
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@dudigital/react-native-zoomable-view": "^1.0.15",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^7.1.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^7.1.0",
    "@sentry/react-native": "^1.7.2",
    "amplitude-js": "5.5.0-react-native.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "axios-extensions": "^3.0.6",
    "date-fns": "^2.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "query-string": "^6.8.3",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "^0.63.2",
    "react-native-android-dialog-picker": "^0.1.0",
    "react-native-autogrow-textinput": "^5.3.0",
    "react-native-background-fetch": "2.7.1",
    "react-native-background-geolocation": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-background-timer": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-branch": "^4.3.0",
    "react-native-camera": "^3.8.0",
    "react-native-dash": "^0.0.11",
    "react-native-device-info": "^5.6.5",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.7",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "1.6.1",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.1",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.25.0",
    "react-native-material-textfield": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-pdf": "5.0.9",
    "react-native-permissions": "^2.1.5",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.11.0",
    "react-native-signature-capture": "^0.4.10",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.8.4",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^9.13.3",
    "react-native-unimodules": "^0.7.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-walkme-sdk": "^2.0.12",
    "react-native-webview": "9.4.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.0",
    "react-navigation-hooks": "^1.1.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.9.3",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.5.5",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "styled-components": "^4.3.2",
    "tslint": "^5.18.0",
    "ttag": "^1.7.18",
    "yup": "^0.27.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/helper-validator-identifier": "^7.9.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@types/amplitude-js": "^4.4.4",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.15",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.138",
    "@types/node": "^12.6.4",
    "@types/react": "^16.8.22",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.57.64",
    "@types/react-native-dotenv": "^0.2.0",
    "@types/react-native-elements": "^0.18.0",
    "@types/react-native-material-textfield": "^0.12.3",
    "@types/react-native-signature-capture": "^0.4.1",
    "@types/react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.7.4",
    "@types/react-navigation": "^3.0.8",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^16.8.2",
    "@types/styled-components": "^4.1.16",
    "@types/yup": "^0.26.22",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^1.13.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^1.13.0",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "dtslint": "^0.8.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.14.2",
    "husky": "^1.3.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.4",
    "lint-staged": "^8.1.4",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
    "prettier": "^1.18.2",
    "react-native-asset": "1.1.4",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^0.2.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0",
    "reactotron-react-native": "^4.0.2",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0",
    "tslint-react": "^4.0.0",
    "tslint-react-hooks": "^2.2.1",
    "ttag-cli": "^1.7.22",
    "typescript": "3.5.2",
    "typescript-styled-plugin": "^0.15.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

App.tsx:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { PermissionsAndroid, Platform, Alert } from 'react-native';
import branch from 'react-native-branch';
import { NavigationState, NavigationContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen';
import amplitude from 'amplitude-js';
import AmplitudeClient from 'amplitude-js';
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';
import { useLocale } from 'ttag';
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';

import getAppNavigator from './navigation/AppNavigator';
import config from './config';
import theme from './theme';
import { getItem, setItem } from './utils/storage';
import { getActiveRouteName, getActiveRouteParams } from './navigation/utils';
import { fetchToken, AccessToken, FetchTokenParams } from './services/auth';
import { areParamsForOnboarding } from './services/branch';
import { usePublicFetch } from './hooks/fetching';
import { LocaleProvider, Locale, updateLocale, getLocaleFromStorage } from './locale';




const App = () => {
  const [AppNavigator, setAppNavigator] = useState<NavigationContainer>();
  const branchParams = useRef<branch.Params>();

  const [query, fetchTokenParams] = usePublicFetch<AccessToken, FetchTokenParams>(fetchToken);

  const [realizarQuery, setRealizarQuery] = useState(true);


  function finishLoading(accessToken?: string, refreshToken?: string) {
    if (accessToken && refreshToken) {
      config.accessToken = accessToken;
      config.refreshToken = refreshToken;
    }

    setAppNavigator(() => {
      
      if (branchParams.current && areParamsForOnboarding(branchParams.current)) {
        return getAppNavigator(!!accessToken, {
          companyId: branchParams.current.companyId,
          newCompany: branchParams.current.newCompany,
          travelOrderId: branchParams.current.travelOrderId,
        });
      }

      return getAppNavigator(!!accessToken);
    });

    SplashScreen.hide();
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const accessToken = await getItem('accessToken');
      const refreshToken = await getItem('refreshToken');
      const p = await branch.getLatestReferringParams();

      if (accessToken && refreshToken) {
        finishLoading(accessToken, refreshToken);
      } else if (areParamsForOnboarding(p)) {
        branchParams.current = p;

        fetchTokenParams({
          user: p.username,
          pass: p.authorizationcode,
        });
      } else {
        finishLoading();
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (query.data && realizarQuery) {
      setRealizarQuery(false);
      finishLoading(query.data.access_token, query.data.refresh_token);
      savingToken(query.data.access_token, query.data.refresh_token);
    }
  }, [query]);

  if (!AppNavigator) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <AppNavigator
      onNavigationStateChange={(prevState: NavigationState, currentState: NavigationState) => {
        const currentScreen = getActiveRouteName(currentState);
        const prevScreen = getActiveRouteName(prevState);
        const params = getActiveRouteParams(currentState);

        if (prevScreen !== currentScreen) {
          // We also update amplitude every single time a navigation occurs
          amplitude.getInstance().logEvent(`${currentScreen.toLowerCase()}.viewed`, params);
        }
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default () => {
  const [locale, setLocale] = useState<Locale>('en');

  useEffect(() => {
    getLocaleFromStorage().then(storedLocale => {
      useLocale(storedLocale); // ttag change of locale
      setLocale(storedLocale);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <LocaleProvider
        value={{
          locale,
          setLocale: (locale: Locale) => {
            updateLocale(locale); // ttag & async storage change of locale
            setLocale(locale);
          },
        }}
      >
        <App />
      </LocaleProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};
```

**getAppNavigator**

```
import React from 'react';
import { createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import { ButtonComponentProps } from 'react-navigation-tabs/lib/typescript/src/types';

import BottomTab from './BottomTab';
import MyLoads from '../screens/MyLoads';
import TravelOrder from '../screens/TravelOrder';
import ArriveWorkflow from '../screens/ArriveWorkflow';
import LoadWorkflow from '../screens/LoadWorkflow';
import DeliverWorkflow from '../screens/DeliverWorkflow';
import OfferedWorkflow from '../screens/OfferedWorkflow';
import Feedback from '../screens/Feedback';
import TestBOLScan from '../screens/TestBOLScan';
import Messages from '../screens/Messages';
import Settings from '../screens/Settings';
import FacilityReviewWorkflow from '../screens/FacilityReviewWorkflow';

import OnboardingModal from '../modals/OnboardingModal';
import MapModal from '../modals/MapModal';
import WebViewModal from '../modals/WebViewModal';
import DocumentModal from '../modals/DocumentModal';
import DocumentUploadModal from '../modals/DocumentUploadModal';
import RequestPayModal from '../modals/RequestPayModal';
import CompletionModal from '../modals/CompletionModal';
import FacilityReviewModal from '../modals/FacilityReviewModal';

import AuthStack from './AuthStack';
import { noHeader, commonStack } from './common';
import {
  FEEDBACK,
  MY_LOADS,
  TRAVEL_ORDER,
  ARRIVE_WORKFLOW,
  LOAD_WORKFLOW,
  DELIVER_WORKFLOW,
  OFFERED_WORKFLOW,
  TEST_BOL_SCAN,
  MESSAGES,
  ONBOARDING_MODAL,
  MAP_MODAL,
  WEB_VIEW_MODAL,
  DOCUMENT_MODAL,
  DOCUMENT_UPLOAD_MODAL,
  REQUEST_PAY_MODAL,
  COMPLETION_MODAL,
  SETTINGS,
  FACILITY_REVIEW_MODAL,
  FACILITY_REVIEW_WORKFLOW,
} from './screenNames';

import { OnboardingParams } from '../navigationTypes';
import theme from '../theme';

export default function getAppContainer(hasToken?: boolean, initialParams?: OnboardingParams) {
  const MyLoadsStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
      [MY_LOADS]: {
        screen: MyLoads,
        params: initialParams,
        navigationOptions: noHeader,
      },
      [TRAVEL_ORDER]: {
        screen: TravelOrder,
        navigationOptions: noHeader,
      },
      [ARRIVE_WORKFLOW]: {
        screen: ArriveWorkflow,
        navigationOptions: noHeader,
      },
      [LOAD_WORKFLOW]: {
        screen: LoadWorkflow,
        navigationOptions: noHeader,
      },
      [DELIVER_WORKFLOW]: {
        screen: DeliverWorkflow,
        navigationOptions: {
          ...noHeader,
          gesturesEnabled: false,
        },
      },
      [TEST_BOL_SCAN]: {
        screen: TestBOLScan,
        navigationOptions: noHeader,
      },
      [OFFERED_WORKFLOW]: {
        screen: OfferedWorkflow,
        navigationOptions: noHeader,
      },
      [FACILITY_REVIEW_WORKFLOW]: {
        screen: FacilityReviewWorkflow,
        navigationOptions: noHeader,
      },
      ...commonStack,
    },
    { headerMode: 'none' },
  );

  const FeedbackStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
      [FEEDBACK]: {
        screen: Feedback,
        navigationOptions: noHeader,
      },
      ...commonStack,
    },
    { headerMode: 'none' },
  );

  const MessagesStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
      [MESSAGES]: {
        screen: Messages,
        navigationOptions: noHeader,
      },
      ...commonStack,
    },
    { headerMode: 'none' },
  );

  const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
      [SETTINGS]: {
        screen: Settings,
        navigationOptions: noHeader,
      },
      ...commonStack,
    },
    { headerMode: 'none' },
  );

  const LoggedInStack = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
      [MY_LOADS]: {
        screen: MyLoadsStack,
      },
      [FEEDBACK]: {
        screen: FeedbackStack,
      },
      [MESSAGES]: {
        screen: MessagesStack,
      },
      [SETTINGS]: {
        screen: SettingsStack,
      },
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: MY_LOADS,
      defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
        const tabBarButtonComponent = ({ focused, onPress }: ButtonComponentProps) => (
          <BottomTab routeName={navigation.state.routeName} focused={focused} onPress={onPress} />
        );

        return {
          tabBarButtonComponent,
          tabBarOptions: {
            activeTintColor: theme.color.white,
            inactiveTintColor: '#9e9e9e',
            style: {
              backgroundColor: '#252525',
            },
            labelStyle: {
              fontFamily: 'Avenir-Black',
              fontSize: 13,
            },
          },
        };
      },
    },
  );

  return createAppContainer(
    createSwitchNavigator(
      {
        Auth: AuthStack,
        Main: createStackNavigator(
          {
            LoggedInStack: {
              screen: LoggedInStack,
            },
            [ONBOARDING_MODAL]: {
              screen: OnboardingModal,
            },
            [MAP_MODAL]: {
              screen: MapModal,
            },
            [WEB_VIEW_MODAL]: {
              screen: WebViewModal,
            },
            [DOCUMENT_MODAL]: {
              screen: DocumentModal,
            },
            [DOCUMENT_UPLOAD_MODAL]: {
              screen: DocumentUploadModal,
            },
            [REQUEST_PAY_MODAL]: {
              screen: RequestPayModal,
            },
            [COMPLETION_MODAL]: {
              screen: CompletionModal,
            },
            [FACILITY_REVIEW_MODAL]: {
              screen: FacilityReviewModal,
            },
          },
          {
            mode: 'modal',
            headerMode: 'none',
          },
        ),
      },
      {
        initialRouteName: hasToken ? 'Main' : 'Auth',
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

The problem is in **setAppNavigator**

```
setAppNavigator(() => {
      if (branchParams.current && areParamsForOnboarding(branchParams.current)) {
        return getAppNavigator(!!accessToken, {
          companyId: branchParams.current.companyId,
          newCompany: branchParams.current.newCompany,
          travelOrderId: branchParams.current.travelOrderId,
        });
      }
```

Before the update was working correctly, **getAppNavigator** is a function that is returning a Component 'NavigationContainer'.

After the update start to show the error in **setAppNavigator**:
[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6np8f.jpg)

I assume that **setAppNavigator** it's expecting an JSX.element like this:

"< AppNavigator> < /AppNavigator>"

And it's not possible to use a function that it will return the same component anymore.

**Q:** It's there other way to keep using NavigationContainer as a function ?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Where is `getAppNavigator`? Does it return a component? Or a function?

Comment: `getAppNavigator` is a function that returns a component of type 'NavigationContainer', I added to the question